# Windows 'start' command not executing with child_process.exec in VS Code plugin

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd, visual-studio-code, electron

I am trying to start a program from a VS Code plugin through the `child_process.exec()` function but the program doesn't start. If I execute the same command from the `cmd` shell directly, the program runs normally...

I build the command like this:

```
var cmd ='start /d "' + process.env['DECKARD_PATH'] + '"' + " /b Deckard.exe"
// cmd resolves to 'start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Deckard" /b Deckard.exe'
```

and then try to execute:

```
child_process.exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  // Some stuff but no errors are triggered...
})
```

Note that Deckard.exe is an electron application with Windows UI.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: __START__ is an internal command of Windows command interpreter `cmd.exe` and not an executable in System32 folder of Windows. So you have to run `cmd.exe /C ...`.

Comment: Same issue, nothing happens. My understanding is that `child_process.exec()` is supposed to run the `cmd` in the context of `cmd.exe` shell on Windows (and `bash` on Linux)

Comment: Why do you use `cmd.exe` and command __START__ at all? The current working directory can be defined in options of child process according to [Node.js Child Processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) documentation. Do you really need the background option `/B` of command __START__? According to this documentation `spawn` instead of `exec` needs to be used. Note: I'm having no knowledge about Node.js, just about Windows command line. So I'm shooting already in sky with this suggestion and hope for giving nevertheless some useful input on your problem.